# Cuda Installation Error

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, nvidia, ubuntu-18.04

I installed Cuda on My Ubuntu 18.04(Dual Boot with windows 10) using the following Commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

sudo apt update

sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Then ReBooted my Computer.

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit gcc-6
```

Then verified the installation using

```
nvcc --version
which nvcc
```

Both worked well without any errors. After few days I wanted verify it completely when I entered these 2 commands

```
sudo modprobe nvidia
nvidia-smi
```

which gave me this error respectively

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Required key not available
>
> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

Now I am unable to understand if Cuda is properly installed or not. I am also unable to find Cuda-9.0 in "usr" file inside ubuntu. I need this so that I can work with tensorflow-gpu (Python3).

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: This is likely to be a UEFI or  secure boot issue. See https://askubuntu.com/q/761886. But this question is off topic for [SO] and I have voted to close out. You world be much better served asking at a Linux support site like askubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the "required key not available" message is a typical  (side-)effect of the "secure boot" feature of newer Linux kernels (`EFI_SECURE_BOOT_SIG_ENFORCE`); and you may be able to get around it by **Disabling Secure Boot in your UEFI BIOS**.

See this AskUbuntu question for details:

[Why do I get “Required key not available” when install 3rd party kernel modules or after a kernel upgrade?](http://%20https://askubuntu.com/q/762254/193641)

Comment: This almost certainly won't help and has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Hmm... that's just the mean @talonmies way to make me look for another answer. Thanks, my friend; tough love :-)

Comment: This could be something as subtle as a Windows side update (note it is a dual boot system) changing a UEFI setting which now inhibits loading of 3rd party binary kernel modules.